# How to setup credentials for every project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins

I have some 10 projects in my Jenkins , each for 10 different clients . So i need to create credentials for all my projects , so that each client can access only their project .

Is there any plugin to achieve my requirement .??

Please Help !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy" under Global Security

Define general users, without access to projects at this level.

Then on per-project select "Enable project-based security", and here you can give individual users addition permissions, such as ability to view and execute the job

**Edit:**

In **Configure Global Security**, under **Project-based Matrix Authorization**:

- Make sure **Anonymous** and **Authenticated** don't have any other permissions.
- Give *Anonymous*:

  - **Job Discover** (this will redirect non-logged in users to login page).
- Give *Authenticated*:

  - **Overall Read** (without this permission, nothing else will work).
  - **View Read**, optional (without this, they won't see custom views, just the 'all view').
- Save configuration

In **Job Configuration**, under **Enable project-based security**:

- Give *client1*:

  - **Job Read** (this will allow to view this particular job, and nothing else).
  - Give additional permissions as required (build, workspace, promote, etc).
- Save configuration

Comment: Thanks , Its working . But in my DashBord , im able to see all the 10 projects . But my requirement is say when client1 logs in ,he should be able to see only project1 in the dashbord . But here he is able to see all 10 projects . Hope you got my point .

Comment: @Slav how about the role strategy plugin will it help in the above requirement.And which is the better solution

Comment: @RCBian, I've used it. It's functional and does everything you'd want it to, however.... it has a huge impact on UI performance. I've spent several days figuring out why my Jenkins became slow and unresponsive all of a sudden, even defragged the disks. In the end, it turned out to be that plugin. I am not the only one reporting this either http://soldering-iron.blogspot.ca/2014/01/jenkins-performance-hints.html

Comment: @Slav I started using jenkins 15 days ago.I have extracted the .war file to run jenkins.But sometimes I get problems(like jenkins shows user is missing overall/read permission) very oftenly,thats why i thought of moving role strategy plugin

Comment: @Slav the problem occurs when i close the command prompt using which I extracted jenkins.I am not able to detrmine why i get these sort of errors that why i thought of foccusing on Role strategy

Comment: @RCBian, if you Jenkins behaves differently once you close the command prompt, this is an installation issue, I doubt the Role Strategy plugin would help. Sorry, can't be of more help