# Jenkins: User wise project view configuration

Tags: jenkins, plugins, devops

I want to configure user wise project view. For example , if there is project A,B, and C and Users: X and Y, I want to configure like user A can view all projects but user Y can see only C.

Is it possible through any plugin or should be done manually?

I do not want to give overall read permission to anyone. I want to strictly restrict each project view for related/specific user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup credentials for every project in Jenkins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393169/how-to-setup-credentials-for-every-project-in-jenkins)

Comment: @Christopher Orr
The answer you provided does not meet my requirement . I explained a little more my question.

Comment: That plugin does what you want. You can configure permissions per project.

Comment: Thanks. I could solve it . At first I could not find the "Enable project based security " section and was searching this in " Configure Global Security " .

Answer (score 0):

This project based security is in every job's configure window. After configuring `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy`, from `Manage Jenkins` ,it is possible to configure each job's user specific view configuration.

[image]